# PDO out of scope (PHP Composer)

Tags: php, pdo, composer-php

I just started using composer and its autoloader for php. Then I added my own code to the autoloader using psr-0. Everything is fine except when I want to access the PDO (new PDO(...). It seems that its out of scope because the Autoloader expects it in my package (called MyAPP). The Error I am getting is:

> PHP Fatal error: Class 'MyApp\PDO' not found in /var/www/ws/src/MyApp/WsDatenbank.php
>   on line 15

My attempts to google ended up unsuccessful. 
Please Help - Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Posting my comment as the answer.

You have to do: `new \PDO()` (note the slash). When doing this you are loading the class for the global namespace. Otherwise it will be loaded from the current namespace (in your case `MyApp`).

Comment: Thanks, in PSR-4 goes like this: in class, `use \PDO;` In effect this is a root  `\PDO` of namespaces.

Comment: I don't see how this is related to PSR4? :P

Comment: Because we use composer as autoloading classmap, and I used root namespace for PDO. Work fine for now. When workig with OOP. More [why use composer PSR](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22803419/why-use-a-psr-0-or-psr-4-autoload-in-composer-if-classmap-is-actually-faster)

Comment: - perhaps not the best solution - [link code](http://pastebin.com/CTCDfZW7) but one of solution