# Composer PSR-4 for application files

Tags: php, json, composer-php, autoload

I am new to using composer and have created a list of required projects in my composer.json file. I can use them within my index.php bootstrap file fine.

However I want to also be able to autoload my own project files outside of the vendor folder using composers autoloader. My folder structure is as follows:

```
vendor/
project/
   Project.php
index.php
composer.json
```

**index.php**

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

new \Project\Project;
```

**Project.php**

```
<?php

namespace Project;

class Project {
}
```

**composer.json**

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Project\\": "project"
        }
    }
}
```

This keeps coming up with the following error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Product\Product' not found in index.php on line 5
```

What am i doing wrong? Or can I not use composers autoload to load my application files?

**Edit**
Turns out I needed to run `composer dump-auto -o` to refresh the changes I made to the `composer.json` file. Credit to @Quasduck who posted in the comments.

Comment: There seems to be a disconnect between the namespace you are declaring and the one you are using.  Are you sure the class you're trying to instantiate shouldn't be `Project\Product\Product` ?

Comment: It should be `new \Project\Project;` - without the trailing `.php`. And also make sure you don't forget to run `composer dump-auto -o` after making changes in the autoload section of your composer.json - And where does that `Product` thing come from in your error message? Is there a Product class involved anywhere?

Comment: @Quasdunk The .php was a typo on SO and isnt in the code itself. The problem was fixed when I run the `composer dump-auto -o` which you suggested and the class was loaded fine :)

Comment: Alright, glad it works now :) Good luck with your project!

Comment: @Quasdunk please post your solution as an answer, so Ozzy can mark the question as solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Posting my comment as an answer*

Whenever you tinker with the autoload section in your `composer.json` file, always make sure to update the autoloader after that by running

```
$ composer dump-autoload -o
```

This is also run automatically after each `composer update` or `composer install`.

Also notice the (optional, but recommended) `-o` param, which tells Composer to optimize the autoloads. This basically means that PSR-0/4 autoloads (like in your example) are converted to simple [classmaps](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#classmap). This can speed up the autoloading significantly, especially in larger projects.

Updating the autloader can also solve issues when you update, rename or move a class but your application doesn't seem to pick up on that.

Comment: I want to question the remark regarding `-o`. I gave some reasons why this is not true in general in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22803419/why-use-a-psr-0-or-psr-4-autoload-in-composer-if-classmap-is-actually-faster/22823995#22823995

Comment: @Sven Thanks for the hint, I didn't actually think of that. Very interesting issue though!