# How to stop PHP Composer autoload require-dev library?

Tags: php, phpunit, composer-php

I use PHPUnit for testing and development only, I don't want my app to autoload them in production server, is it possible?

```
"require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "4.2.*",
..
```

I see the file "autoload_classmap.php" contains lines such as..

```
return array(
    'File_Iterator' => $vendorDir . '/phpunit/php-file-iterator/File/Iterator.php',
    'File_Iterator_Facade' => $vendorDir . '/phpunit/php-file-iterator/File/Iterator/Facade.php',
```

Updated:

I want a clean production env and don't want to autoload phpunit, I only need phpunit during development. So, can composer generate two autoload.php so I can include them depending on my current env?

Answer (score 6):

`--no-dev` : Skip installing packages listed in require-dev

```
composer install --no-dev --optimize-autoloader
```

You will probably also want to do: `--optimize-autoloader` (-o): Convert PSR-0/4 autoloading to classmap to get a faster autoloader. This is recommended especially for production, but can take a bit of time to run so it is currently not done by default.

Comment: Regarding the classmap: Please see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22803419/why-use-a-psr-0-or-psr-4-autoload-in-composer-if-classmap-is-actually-faster/22823995#22823995 Short version: Classmaps are not the fastest way to autoload in EVERY case.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the question. Actually what I want is to generate two autoload.php, one for development, and one for production. Is it possible?

Comment: `--dev` (the default), will install things from the `require-dev` section. `--no-dev` won't install the `require-dev` section. That is what you need.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but the default will also `pollute` the autoload.php, I don't mind to waste the storage space, but I don't want to waste the CPU time in autoloading the stuffs that I never use in production. (Actually it is good to avoid autoloading lib that I don't intended to be used in production)

Comment: @Howard, you don't seem to be grasping the point. In development, it runs with the default - so composer pulls in, and builds the autoloading to include PHPUnit and so on from the require-dev section. In production, when you run composer, you add the --no-dev parameter which does not pull in anything from require-dev.