# Autoload classmap in PHP

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload

I read somewhere that classmap autoloading is faster than PSR-0/PSR-4. Of course for development process is better to use PSR-0/PSR-4. We can easily create a classmap via composer with `-o` param from PSR-0/PSR-4.

**My question**: is classmap autoloading really faster? With all vendors I have almost 3000 classes in my project. It means `autoload_classmap.php` file with 3000 lines (and an array with 3000 items). Is it still faster then autoloading using PSR-0/PSR-4 in production?

Comment: Can anyone reliably answer this question without creating a classmap autoloader with 3000 entries and benchmarking it vs. some "average" scenario where a "reasonable" (but arbitrary) number of classes are loaded with PSR-0 or PSR-4?

Comment: Classmap lookups are by definition faster. Their drawback is usually the memory consumption. OTOH you already scattered your class definitions over 3000 files (due to PSR-x) instead of conjoining dependent ones. So it's unlikely the concrete autoloader will have a measurable impact.

Answer (score 0):

Please see my answer here: [Why use a PSR-0 or PSR-4 autoload in composer if classmap is actually faster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22803419/why-use-a-psr-0-or-psr-4-autoload-in-composer-if-classmap-is-actually-faster/22823995#22823995)

No need to duplicate everything.