# Configure what composer autoload will map from libraries

Tags: composer-php, autoloader

My application is based requires Zend Framework 1.12 and I am using composer to manage depencies, including Zend Framework itself, PHPUnit and required libraries.

The problem here is the autoloader dumped by composer maps every class from all libraries. I don't use every ZendFramework class, and so, I'd like to replace the Zend Framework default autoloader configuration with my own (maybe completelly ignore it and configure another myself).

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the definition of autoloading for Zend framework 1 uses PSR-0. This will only install a single entry in the Composer autoloader, and nothing else. I wouldn't consider this any kind of annoying.

However, don't "optimize" the autoloader. [This is known to be slower in some cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22803419/why-use-a-psr-0-or-psr-4-autoload-in-composer-if-classmap-is-actually-faster/22823995#22823995).

Comment: The thing is the autoloader_classmap.php lists all files contained in Zend Framework when I only use some of them. I'll try the results of not optimizing.